# Error on build Laravel Project in Gitlab

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build my project but after push on gitlab it returns Error:
[image]

Comment: You need to re-install the same package i.e. doctrine/dbal whenever you will create the new project structure with correct PHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DBAL` version is one that needs php 7 or higher. Pick another version that satisfies php 5.6, like [DBAL 2.5.x](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal#2.5.x-dev)

As a sidenote, this is why it is useful to make your local development environment resemble your production environment. php 7 has features that 5.6 doesn't and you WILL break your software 99.9% of the time.